# Regular expression dilemma when trying to match strings

Tags: regex, delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

This is a line of code in the Delphi 10.3.3 IDE's code editor:

[image]

The blue color identifies the string constant: `'ab''cd'`

Now I try to match the strings in the following subject with a regular expression (System.RegularExpressions):

```
ThisString := 'ab''cd'{'};
OtherString := 'simple';
```

1. If I use the Regex `'.*'` then I get this result in RegexBuddy 4.10:

[image]

2. If I use this other Regex `'.*?'` then I get this result:

[image]

You can see that both Regexes don't match the desired correct result.

How to solve this dilemma?

Comment: Do you mean like this? `(?:'[^\s']+')+(?:{'})?;`  https://regex101.com/r/xLQarK/1 Or like `'[^{}]+'(?:{[^{}]+})?;` https://regex101.com/r/7MOMkM/1

Comment: This doesn't match the strings exactly: https://i.imgur.com/u3KeavI.png

Comment: Do you only want to match `'ab''cd'`?

Comment: Yes, as I asked in the question.

Comment: This would match those stings https://regex101.com/r/nGnncu/1 Or you can use a capturing group to make sure there is a `;` at the end `((?:'[^\s']+')+)[^\s;]*;(?!\S)`  https://regex101.com/r/Vluul9/1

Comment: A more specific match for the strings could be `(?<!\S)((?:'[^\s']+')+)(?:{[^{}]+})?;(?!\S)`  https://regex101.com/r/pAblZI/1

Comment: Thanks, but both do not work with this string: `ThisString := 'ab''''cd'{'};` or with this string: `ThisString := 'ab''''''cd'{'};`

Comment: It does now using `*` as the quantifier instead of `+` See https://regex101.com/r/fbUdRn/1

Comment: The match is too wide: https://i.imgur.com/NM2nSHN.png it should match only the STRINGS.

Comment: It should be something like `'[^']*(?:''[^']*)*'`, see https://regex101.com/r/PWyvrd/1

Comment: Something like `'[^}{]*'` not working right?

Comment: You didn't tell, what the desired correct result is or did I miss something!?

Comment: Don't forget `//` sets the rest of the line to a comment unless it is in a string or `{}` comment block

Answer (score 1):

To get a broad match for the example data and getting a match only instead of a group, you could use lookarounds and a negated character class and  repeating matching 2 single quotes.

```
(?:'[^']*')+(?=[^;]*;)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/A3OTs4/1)

To get a more precise match, you could make use of lookarounds for the whitespace boundaries:

```
(?<!\S)(?:'[^']*')+(?=(?:{[^{}]+})?;(?!\S))
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/nNrt79/1)

To match 1 or more repeating pairs, you could use:

```
 (?:'[^']*')+
```

Comment: Both Regexes do not match this string: `ThisString := 'ab''cd' {'};`

Comment: In that case you can omit the `\s` from the pattern https://regex101.com/r/PytWjb/1

Comment: It should match only if there are zero or unlimited number of PAIRS of single quotes inside the string.

Comment: Strangely, I have found this regex to be seeming to work correctly: `(?:'[^\s']*')+` but it works not correctly if there are white spaces after or before the single quotes inside the string.

Comment: But this regex also doesn't work if the string (= between single quote boundaries) does contain ANY WHITE SPACES). Which means that this does not match: `OtherString := 'si mple'`

Comment: Then you could simplify it to `(?:'[^']*')+` to match 1 or more pairs. Use `*` to match 0 or more pairs.